# Can't bind to 'inputDate' since it isn't a known property of 'x'

Tags: angular, components

Im trying to bind `timediff`variable to the component for furture countdown.
But i get the following:

```
zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'inputDate' since it isn't a known property of 'countdown'. ("

          <div *ngIf="countdown > 0">
            <countdown [ERROR ->]inputDate="{{timediff}}">{{ timediff | date: 'yMMMdjms' }}</countdown>
          </div>


Can't bind to 'inputDate' since it isn't a known property of 'countdown'. ("

          <div *ngIf="countdown > 0">
            <countdown [ERROR ->]inputDate="{{timediff}}">{{ timediff | date: 'yMMMdjms' }}</countdown>
          </div>
```

***How can i make it accept my variable?***

example of timediff value:

```
1494418776073
```

html:

```
 <countdown inputDate="{{timediff}}">{{ timediff | date: 'yMMMdjms' }}</countdown>
```

component:

```
   import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable, Subscription } from "rxjs/Rx"

    @Component({
      selector: 'countdown',
      template: `{{message}}`,
    })
    export class CountdownComponent implements OnInit {
      private future: Date;
      private futureString: string;
      private diff: number;
      private $counter: Observable<number>;
      private subscription: Subscription;
      private message: string;


      constructor(elm: ElementRef) {
        this.futureString = elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('inputDate');
      }

      dhms(t) {
        var days, hours, minutes, seconds;
        days = Math.floor(t / 86400);
        t -= days * 86400;
        hours = Math.floor(t / 3600) % 24;
        t -= hours * 3600;
        minutes = Math.floor(t / 60) % 60;
        t -= minutes * 60;
        seconds = t % 60;

        return [
          hours + 'h',
          minutes + 'm',
          seconds + 's'
        ].join(' ');
      }




      ngOnInit() {
        this.future = new Date(this.futureString);
        this.$counter = Observable.interval(1000).map((x) => {
          this.diff = Math.floor((this.future.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000);
          console.log(x);
          return x;
        });

        this.subscription = this.$counter.subscribe((x) => this.message = this.dhms(this.diff));

      }
      ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
      }


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add below code to `CountdownComponent`.

```
@Input()
inputDate: string;
```

and use it in your template as below:

```
<countdown [inputDate]="timediff">{{ timediff | date: 'yMMMdjms' }}</countdown>
```

Comment: thanks! any reason why im no longer able to get the inputDate?

Comment: @maria refer https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: thanks. accepted your answer. You are freely to check out my other topics with my problems :)

Comment: @maria ok, that's great!